# CheckBox CheckedChange event in RadGridEditForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

[image]I have a RadGridEditForm Template, Where i have checkBox and RadComboBox.

So it contains 2 buttons

1st-Add New Record (Which is GridEditFormInsertItem)

2nd- Edit(To edit the existing record.)

I want to Disable the RadComboBox when the **checkbox is **CHECKED****
I used to folowing code its working fine with 'Add New Record' but not when i click on **Edit** button its showing error as-

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem' to type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormInsertItem'.
```

My code for checkedChanged Event is

```
    protected void chkEHalfDay_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkHalfDay = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridEditFormInsertItem item = (GridEditFormInsertItem)chkHalfDay.NamingContainer;

        if (chkHalfDay.Checked == false)
        {
            ((RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rcbHalfDayType")).Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ((RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rcbHalfDayType")).Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

Please Suggest where i went wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void chkEHalfDay_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CheckBox chkHalfDay = (CheckBox)sender;
   //GridEditFormInsertItem item = (GridEditFormInsertItem)chkHalfDay.NamingContainer;
   GridEditFormInsertItem item = chkHalfDay.NamingContainer as GridEditFormInsertItem;
   if(item == null)
     item = hkHalfDay.NamingContainer as GridEditFormItem;

  if (chkHalfDay.Checked == false)
     ((RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rcbHalfDayType")).Enabled = false;
  else
      ((RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rcbHalfDayType")).Enabled = true;
}
```

Just use `as` operator because it won't raise any error of invalid cast it'll simply return `null` which you can check in next line if `chkHalfDay.NamingContainer` isn't `GridEditFormInsertItem` then cast it to `GridEditFormItem` which is at the time of Edit operation.